# How can you detect the pressure with which the screen is pressed?

Tags: c++, qt, n900

Hey all .. i wanted to know, in C++/Qt, how can one detect with how much pressure the screen is being pressed when a project is on the N900 ?.. Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Its very much possible to get pressure data. In GTK/GDK you register for all extension events with [gtk_widget_set_extension_events()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-extension-events)

```
gtk_widget_set_extension_events(widget, GDK_EXTENSION_EVENTS_ALL);
```

and you will start receiving move/pressure events as well. The link Olorin posted could be the Qt interface for the same, but I haven't used it so cannot say for sure.